# Move gameobject according to swipe along x axis in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, swipe

I am trying to move object in unity along the x axis and in the direction of swipe while remaining inside of the screen. It should move as much as distance as the user swipes (much like Ketchapp's rush hero).

Here is my code so far in update:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) // Get initial Position
            {
                playerPos = transform.position;
                //playerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (playerPos);
                touchPos = Input.GetTouch (0).position;
                touchPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (touchPos);
                distance = 0f;

            } 
            else if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
            {
                Vector3 pos = Input.GetTouch (0).position;
                pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
                distance = pos.x - touchPos.x;
                transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + distance, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            }

        }
```

This doesn't work properly and I am a rookie in unity. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what it is doing currently that is wrong?

Comment: It moves the gameobject way more than it should and it goes out of screen

Comment: why not just update the position directly to where the touch is instead of adding the distance ?  
`transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

Comment: I suspect that the "move" portion is being called multiple times but your code assumes it happens once. The first frame the user swipes 10 pixels (lets say that's 1 world unit), the cube moves over 1 unit. The next frame the user keeps swiping, another 10 pixels. Well now we take the cube's current position (1 unit over) and add (current_pos - start_pos) which is 20 pixels and thus move the cube over *another 2 units* so now it's at (3,0,0) whereas we want it at (2,0,0).

Comment: @Draco18s I am guessing that's correct. What's the workaround that ?

Comment: Option a) reset your startPoint. Option b) don't use cumulative offsets.

Comment: Fixed it by adding 
touchPos = pos;
to the end... 
You can post your comment as answer with this code and I will mark it as right answer @Draco18s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `TouchPhase.Moved` happens more than once (every frame during the gesture until it ends). But your code assumes that it is only called once.

You have two options here.

- Option 1: Reset the starting point

Add `touchPos = Input.GetTouch (0).position;` as the last line of your `TouchPhase.Moved` block. This will effectively indicate "this distance was already handled, next frame treat the move as a new move and this is where to start from."

- Option 2: Use absolute offsets

Change the last line of your `TouchPhase.Moved` block to `transform.position = new Vector3 (distance, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`.  This will treat every frame as if every move is treated as an offset from the original starting point and set the X value accordingly.  However, this assumes that the object starts at 0 and will always start at 0 along the X-axis.

Depending on your use-case you may prefer one method over the other.